# Image Radio Buttons - NFL Weekly

Tags: asp.net, css, image, radio-button

I've chosen to use this code to construct an application for weekly NFL picks. Can anyone assist in helping me hide the generic radio buttons? I would like to gather all of the picks per individual.

HTML

```
 <div class="buttons" runat="server">
    <input type="radio" name="gp1" id="gpBAL" value="working" />
        <label for="gpBAL" class="working"><span>BAL</span></label>

    <input type="radio" name="gp1" id="gpNC" value="not checked" checked/>
        <label for="gpNC" class="not_checked"><span>&nbsp;||</span></label>

    <input type="radio" name="gp1" id="gpWAS" value="faulty" />
        <label for="gpWAS" class="faulty"><span>WAS</span></label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  body{font-family: helvetica;}
  input[type="radio"]{ -webkit-appearance:none;}
  input[type="radio"]+label
  { 
   background: url('../images/switch.png') repeat-x; 
   float: left;
   display:Block;
  } 
  input[type="radio"] + label span
  {
   display: block;
   background: url('../images/switch.png') no-repeat;
   display: block;
   line-height: 30px;
  }
  input[type="radio"]+label.working span
  {
   background-position: left -90px; padding: 0 10px; 
  }
  input[type="radio"]+label.not_checked span
  {
   padding: 0 10px; 
  }
  input[type="radio"]+label.faulty span
  {
  background-position: right -180px; padding: 0 10px; 
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked+label
  {
  background-position: left -60px;
  }  
  input[type="radio"]:checked+label.working span
  {
  background-position: left -150px;
  color: white;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked+label.faulty span
  {
    background-position: right -240px;
    color: white;
  }

  input[type="radio"]:checked+label.not_checked
  {
    background-position: left -30px;
    color: white;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input[type="radio"] {display: none;}
```

hides the radio buttons.